# mtx returns an error in Windows for an LTO library

Tags: windows

I have been using the mtx utility (from Sourceforge) with success in both Linux and Windows environments to manage a tape library. It was last modified in 2008.

Today, at a customer site, we used the following device id (from Windows Device Manager) to inquire on the inventory of the library, but received an error. I am concerned whether mtx (for Windows) allows a target of 2 digits, or is it something else ? The following is the command I submitted, followed by the error. Any ideas what could be the problem ?

```
C:\BackBox_AutoLoader>mtx.exe -f 5:0:23:1 status
mtx: Request Sense: Long Report=yes
mtx: Request Sense: Valid Residual=no
mtx: Request Sense: Error Code=0 (Unknown?!)
mtx: Request Sense: Sense Key=No Sense
mtx: Request Sense: FileMark=no
mtx: Request Sense: EOM=no
mtx: Request Sense: ILI=no
mtx: Request Sense: Additional Sense Code = 00
mtx: Request Sense: Additional Sense Qualifier = 00
mtx: Request Sense: BPV=no
mtx: Request Sense: Error in CDB=no
mtx: Request Sense: SKSV=no
INQUIRY command Failed
```

Comment: `mtx` has not been updated since 2008 and the support links are dead. Have you taken a look at the source code to try to track down the error?

Comment: Which Windows version are used at your site and in the customer's?

Comment: doneal24: I have started putting some diagnostics into mtx source. We will test again tomorrow.

Comment: harrymc: Should the Windows version matter ? Anyway, it happens to be a Windows 2019 server.

Comment: And we are using Windows 2016 server internally, where it works fine.

Comment: Solved! The device id from Device Manager on Windows was not correct. We had to use the IBM Tape Diagnostic Tool to get the correct device id ! When we used those values, the mtx worked perfectly. Go figure :-|.